# Is the AES encryption scheme CPA secure?

Tags: aes, chosen-plaintext-attack

Give a 256 bit key space and 128 message space would AES block cipher as the encryption scheme be CPA secure?

Comment: AES is just a primitive. You should describe how you use it to build an actual encryption scheme. And how do you use the IV?

Comment: @CodesInChaos Reading this back (a comment pointed to it) I think the AES block cipher *is* an encryption scheme. One that only accepts 128 bit messages, but that seems to be the defined message space in the question.

Answer (score 5):

You are mistaken about what an encryption scheme is. As CodeInChaos pointed out AES is a primitive and we assume that it is a preudo random permutation. That is an assumption since the way AES is built means that we won't be able to formally prove that it is one. With that PRP we try to build modes of encryption that might or might not be CPA-secure
I encourage you to read Mihir Bellare course notes and especially the chapters about Symmetric encryption and pseudo random functions http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/cse207/

Comment: AES is also an encryption scheme is you consider it as a way to encrypt 128 bits blocks

Answer (score 2):

Using AES with a random oracle IV as in [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29) or using a unique nonce as in [CTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29) constrction will result in a CPA secure construction. You cannot play with the size of the key. The key is strictly defined in each mode.

Comment: How do you prove AES-CTR is IND-CPA with a unique nonce?